# c# adding controls in winform via plugin dll

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I have a Winform Gui that serves various purposes.  I am creating an additional plugin, that if present, adds another tabpage to my tabcontrol and then adds the required controls, etc.

My question is, am I best coding this into the main app, ie 'if dll present create this view' or should I code it into the dll and use reflection?  Is it possible using reflection?

Thanks/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should maybe look into existing framework that does exactly what you are looking for. For exemple, Managed Extensibility Framework [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/)

> MEF presents a simple solution for the
>   runtime extensibility problem. Until
>   now, any application that wanted to
>   support a plugin model needed to
>   create its own infrastructure from
>   scratch. Those plugins would often be
>   application-specific and could not be
>   reused across multiple
>   implementations. MEF provides a
>   standard way for the host application
>   to expose itself and consume external
>   extensions. Extensions, by their
>   nature, can be reused amongst
>   different applications. However, an
>   extension could still be implemented
>   in a way that is application-specific.
>   Extensions themselves can depend on
>   one another and MEF will make sure
>   they are wired together in the correct
>   order (another thing you won't have to
>   worry about). MEF offers a set of
>   discovery approaches for your
>   application to locate and load
>   available extensions.

Or if you need to be in seperate app domain, you can use Managed Addin Framework [MAF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200.aspx)

But in your case I think MEF should do the trick. 
Might be overkill though if you just have this one scenario ... but it's an option.